# How to approach this weird seemingly intractable "expectation-maximum expansion"?

Tags: probability, optimization, conditional-expectation

Say that we have the following expression:

$$E_0(\max(0,Y_1))$$
Where $E_t$ denotes the expecation at time $t$, conditional on $\{Y_0,...,Y_t\}$. i.e. $E_t(Y_{t+1})=E(Y_{t+1}|Y_0,...,Y_t)$ But now we iterate it, taking the expectation of time $0$ of the maximum of $0$ and our expectation at time $1$:
$$E_0(\max(0,E_1(\max(0,Y_2)))$$
And again:
$$E_0(\max(0,E_1(\max(0,E_2(\max(0,Y_3))))$$
And $T$ times:
$$E_0(\max(0,E_1(\max(0,...E_{T-1}(\max(0,Y_T)...))))$$

If the $\max$ operators weren't there, then we would simply apply the law of iterated expectations to get $E_0(Y_T)$. But we cannot do this obviously, because of the max functions.

**Is this even remotely tractable? You can assume anything you want about the distribution of $Y_t$, whatever is needed to make it tractable.** I have assumed the normal distribution, but did not get even beyond a single iteration. (I'm ok with approximations). I actually need $Y_t$ to have not-necessarily-zero mean, but I suspect that this will also make it less tractable.

Comment: How is $Y$ related to time? Is time a random variable?

Comment: In one interpretation of this problem, each of the $E_t(\max(0,Y))$ is a non-random constant, conditional on nothing, so the innermost expectation is the only one with any action, resulting in the final answer $E_T(\max(0,Y))$.  More likely, the OP has a filtration (or system of conditioning variables) he has not bothered to tell us about.

Comment: @kimchilover, indeed, I apologize, I forgot to mention this. $Y_t$ is a time dependent variable.

Comment: @madprob, I've edited the question.